# Software Updater Failed to download repositories 13.04

Tags: updates, software-center

My software Updater is no longer working. the computer tells me i need to check from updates, it shows a red triangle symbol that if you click it give me an option to show updates but when i do the software updater either doesn't open or takes an extrodinary long time to do so. When i finally do get it open it either says that the software is update or checks for updates and fails to download repositories. I'm not very knowledgeable about linux or ubuntu yet so if i could get some help that would be great.

these are the last few lines of what the terminal outputed:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Try to type in terminal the following and paste the output in your question: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade`

Comment: Check [this answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/92897/12218)

Answer (score 0):

It is very normal for you to get this because if you take a look at their [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~deluge-team/+archive/ppa) you will notice that they `DO NOT` have a package for ***`raring`*** witch comes from raring ringtail witch is the code name for Ubuntu 13.04.
Afther you remove those repositories everything will be back to normal

[Link on how to remove repository](http://www.maketecheasier.com/remove-repositories-in-ubuntu/2010/05/27).

Comment: So could you explain to me which repositorie needs to be removed? just the ones with the 404 errors right?

Comment: yes, the ones with 404 error